# backbone view with underscore template how to avoid wrapping the template in the view.tag element

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Typically in backbone/underscore templates we have the template

```
<script type="text/template" id="something">
    <%=value%>
</script>
```

when we instantiate it in a view we get the content wrapped in an element. So the following statement

```
template: _.template($('#something').html()),
```

will produce a markup like

```
<div>MyValueHere</div>
```

What I would like to do is to specify that wrapping element in the template
i.e.

```
<script type="text/template" id="something">
    <div>
       <%=value%>
    </div>
</script>
```

so when calling

```
template: _.template($('#something').html()),
```

the result I would like to have is

```
<div>
    MyValueHere
</div>
```

and not the following (which is the result of wrapping the template in the tag found in the view of backbone)

```
<div>
    <div>
        MyValueHere
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to do that efficiently? Would really appreciate a jsFiddle if it's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern in `render` looks like this:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.append(this.template(...));
    return this;
}
```

but you could replace the usual [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) call with a [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) call to replace the view's `el` with one of your own:

```
render: function() {
    this.setElement(this.template(...));
    return this;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/t977y/

You'll still have a `<div>` created in `this.el` before your `setElement` call but that probably doesn't matter that much.

Comment: setElement works like a charm! What can I override or change to avoid the creation of this.el before the setElement?

Comment: I think you'd have to do some surgery on the `Backbone.View` constructor function itself, that [calls `_ensureElement`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.1.0/backbone.js#L986) which will create the `<div>` if the view doesn't have an `el` already.

Comment: hm, sounds like it needs it there 'cause it's using it further in the constructor to bind events, etc. hm, tricky but kinda doable if I can allocate the item on constructor. Thanks man!